# Basic Boolean expression in Python producing surprising results

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean-expression

In Python I have `2>3 == False` which gives `False`. But I'm expecting `True`. If I use parenthesis i.e `(2>3) == False` then I'm getting `True`. What is the theory behind this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is because of a feature of Python which is quite unusual compared to other programming languages, which is that you can write two or more comparisons in a sequence and it has the meaning which is intuitive to mathematicians. For example, an expression like `0 < 5 < 10` is `True` because `0 < 5 and 5 < 10` is `True`.

[From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons):

> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily; for example, `x < y <= z` is equivalent to `x < y and y <= z`, except that `y` is evaluated only once (but in both cases `z` is not evaluated at all when `x < y` is found to be false).

So, the expression `2 > 3 == False` is equivalent to `2 > 3 and 3 == False`, which is `False`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, `2 > 3 == False` is evaluated as `2 > 3 and 3 == False`.

This para from the Python reference should clarify:

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority,
>   which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise
>   operation.
>
> Comparisons can be chained arbitrarily, e.g., x < y <= z is equivalent
>   to x < y and y <= z, except that y is evaluated only once (but in both
>   cases z is not evaluated at all when x < y is found to be false).

Answer (score 1):

[Comparision Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

all the 8 comparison operators have the same precedence. 
so in `2 > 3 and 3 == False` the evaluation is from left to Right
first `2>3` is evaluated. the next condition `3==False` will only be evaluated if the first expression holds true. But here 2>3 holds false hence it returns false and doesn't even evaluates third expression